# Puppet stdlib keys() function syntax error

Tags: puppet

I'm sure I'm doing something silly, but I can't work out the correct syntax for the [stdlib keys() function](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/stdlib#keys) and can't find any examples on the internet.

Here is what I've tried:

```
file { ["/tmp/file1", "/tmp/file2"]:   # <-- this works as expected
  ensure => present,
}

$hash = {"/tmp/file1" => 1, "/tmp/file2" => 2}
file { keys($hash):                    # <-- syntax error occurs here
  ensure => present,
}
```

It results in this error:

> Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on
>   SERVER: Syntax error at ':'; expected '}' at
>   /etc/puppet/modules/slony/manifests/master.pp:113 on node slonymaster

What am I missing? I'm using Puppet 3.6.2 with stdlib 4.3.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just overtaxing your expressions. The idea is sound, but you will have to take an intermediate step.

```
$filenames = keys($hash)
file { $filenames: ensure => present }
```

Puppet will only accept literal array values or variables as resource titles.